# Write new field with CSV writer

Tags: python, excel, csv, writer

I am trying to write a new row on CSV A based on the ID number if the ID number. For example as seen on CSV B if ID = 1 then the student is a Female, ID = 2 is a Male.

CSV A (has 3 columns)

```
ID, Age, FirstName
1,   18,   Lia
2,   18,   Joe
2,   18,   John
```

CSV B (has 2 columns)

```
ID, Gender
1,    Female
2,    Male
```

Based on this information the desired output is below:

```
ID, Age, FirstName, Gender
1,   18,   Lia,     Female
2,   18,   Joe,     Male
2,   18,   John,    Male
```

How can I achieve this using the Python csv writer?

Comment: what, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: Use `pandas` [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for this

Comment: @RJAdriaansen: The question asks how to do it with the `csv.writer` in the `csv` module.

Comment: So all the IDs in CSV A will be either `1` or `2` (and therefore match one of those in CSV B)? This would seem to indicate that in CSV A the ID is really Gender — so why keep both fields in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are doing good, well this logic is basic but as you mentioned above you are new to python so I have done some code for your reference which is attached below

```
    import csv
    newColumn = ''
    genderDict = {}
    with open('CSVB.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        line_count = 0

        for row in csv_reader: 
            if line_count == 0:
                newColumn = row[1]
                line_count = line_count+1
            else:
                genderDict[row[0]] = row[1]

    with open('CSVA.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        line_count = 0
        for row in csv_reader:
            if line_count == 0:
                with open('OUTPUT.csv', mode='w') as employee_file:
                    output_writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=',',  quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                    row.append(newColumn)
                    output_writer.writerow(row)
                line_count += 1
            else:
                with open('OUTPUT.csv', mode='a') as employee_file:
                    output_writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                    row.append(genderDict[row[0]])
                    output_writer.writerow(row)
                line_count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly u understand the thing here
But ig it will go something like this

First create a new csv writer object
Then write the logic code
Append values to a list or tuple
The  say
wobj.writerow(list-name)